# C# ASP.NET Web API download files: the remote host closed the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-api-testing

We have an ASP.NET Web API running on the .NET Framework 4.8 that will download files from a SQL Server FileStream (`.exe`, `.txt`, etc.) and API Load Tester that will simulate the nth concurrent downloads (200, 500, 800, 1000, 1200, 1500).

We have a load testing for the same file which is 5 MB.

We are having 100% success rate at 800 concurrent downloads but on 1k+ downloads getting error:

> The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070E3

> The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD

Steps already taken:

1. Updated the max worker process to 2 or 4 and it doesn't seem to affect the number of concurrent downloads processing:

[image]

2. Ensure that the API Load Tester client timeout is 1 day:

```
var client = new HttpClient() 
{ 
    BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress), 
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1) 
};
```

3. Modified the timeout max pool of database connections of our ASP.NET Web API
4. Monitor the number of concurrent downloads in IIS, and all has been accepted but the processing doesn't start immediately.

It's still failing at 1k+ downloads.

Our performance requirements is to have 100% success rate on 1.5k-2k concurrent downloads

- How can we increase the number of concurrent downloads?
- Is there something in ASP.NET Web API that causes the closure of client connection?